# Downgrade the sql server version in sharepoint server

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql, server

Need urgent help.
I have installed sharepoint server 2019 with sql server 2016 enterprise edition.  clients were using it. Evaluation period is over and site is not opening now.

How easy it will be to downgrade to sqlserver standard edition and will it affect the sharepoint.
Any strps to downgrade without affecting sharepoint?

Please help, its urgent sharepoint is down now.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could build a 2016 SQL server standard and mount the existing databases to is (not sure if there will be an issue since they were previously attached to an Enterprise Edition instance).

From SharePoint’s perspective, the new SQL server will need to be the exact same name/instance name unless you used a SQL alias when you installed SP (then just update the alias).  You can’t update the connection string SharePoint uses to connect to the configuration database once it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL alias to change SQL